# Public Methods for all activities

Tags: android

I have a class called myConstants and in it i list all my constants so when i need them I just reference MyConstants.MYCONSTANT. However, i would like to implement something like this for methods. i am repeating a lot of code, for instance, i have a formatCalendarString(Calendar c) method in 3 activities. seems redundant and unecessary. but i cant make them static because i get static calling non-static errors and the only other way i can think is to make a MyConstant object then call public functions off that object, like this...

```
MyConstants myConstants = new MyConstants();
myConstants.formatCalendarString(Calendar.getInstance());
```

is there some way i can just call the formatCalendarString() inside MyConstants class without generating an object?

Comment: use Singleton class and use methods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517702/singleton-in-android

Comment: take a look from here https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use singleton pattern to cache instances.  Keeping methods in something like parent activity does not make any sense (as primary role of activity is user interaction).

Example:

```
public class MyConstants {
    private static MyConstants ourInstance;

    private MyConstants() {
        //private constructor to limit direct instantiation
    }

    public synchronized static MyConstants getInstance() {
        //if null then only create instance
        if (ourInstance ==null) {
            ourInstance = new MyConstants();
        }
        //otherwise return cached instance
        return ourInstance;
    }

}
```

You just need a `private constructor` and `public static` method that would only generate instance if it is `null`.

Then, call `MyConstants.getInstance().whateverMethod()`. It will create only single instance.

However when using singleton, please keep [memory leaks in mind](https://nfrolov.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/android-using-context-statically-and-in-singletons/). Do not pass activity context directly inside singletons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all methods in activities, you can put then in abstract class `BaseActivity`, which extends `Activity`, and then make your activities extends `BaseActivity`. However, if these methods doesn't correspond to something about activity, I suggest some Singleton or Util class

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Pier Giorgio Misley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41552179/6075635). It's also good to add a private constructor, because you don't obviously want to instantiate an object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Static` keyword.

*Static methods* can be referenced from outside **without istantiating the new object.**

Just create a class:

```
public class MyClassContainingMethods{

  public static String MyStaticMethod(){
    return "I am static!";
  }
}
```

Now call it like

```
String res = MyClassContainingStaticMethods.MyStaticMethod();
```

Hope this helps

**NOTE**

You **CAN** call non-static from static by doing something like this:

```
  public static void First_function(Context context)
  {
    SMS sms = new SMS();
    sms.Second_function(context);
  }

  public void Second_function(Context context)
  {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Hello",1).show(); // This i anable to display and cause crash
  }
```

Example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797459/4700782), you will obiouvsly have to fit it into your needs

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just use a parent class? That way you can just inherit the methods and manage in one source. Then you don't have to use static functions then.

Edit: Like Tomasz Czura said, just extend the Class.

> public class ParentClass {
>
> > public void commonMethod(){
> >     }
> >     }
>
> public class OtherClass extends ParentClass{
>   }